# Properties using private methods in c++

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, properties, private

I have this class :

```
class Size
{
    private:
        int size_x;
        int size_y;

        int GetX( void );
        int GetY( void );
        void PutX( int x );
        void PutY( int y );
    public:
        _declspec ( property ( get = GetX , put = PutX ) ) int X;
        _declspec ( property ( get = GetY , put = PutY ) ) int Y;
};
```

This code will not work because when I try to access X or Y, private methods are used.

How can i make a property that uses functions which CAN'T be used outside the class?

Comment: What if you just let those functions be used as accessors? Why isn't that a solution?

Comment: What language is this? It doesn't look like c++.

Comment: @H2CO3 what do you mean accessors? I am not familiar with that term.. :)

Comment: @juanchopanza this Looks like Microsoft extensions to C++

Comment: @GiwrgosTsopanoglou Accessors are methods whose sole responsibility is to set and get properties.

Comment: @H2CO3 because i want to be able to do this : 
Size.X = 5; int lalala = Size.X;

Comment: @GiwrgosTsopanoglou then you don't even need methods, just public instance variables.

Comment: This is an example class. I actually have a much bigger class that has 12 variables, and i just don't want to use 24 Get Set functions...

Comment: @H2CO3 I need methods because i need to raise some flags when variables are changed

Comment: @H2CO3 but then you loose the ability to trigger something when setting the value of the property.

Comment: @RedX Then you use accessor methods and learn to live with `foo.setBar(42);`, this is so marginal it isn't even worth thinking about.

Comment: @RedX I'm afraid `.` is not an operator, you can't overload that. You'll either have to live with accessors or figure out some ugly hacks with operator overloading.

Comment: "How can i make a property that uses functions which CAN'T be used outside the class?" Why do you want this, why not just make these methods public?

Comment: @hyde i answered that already above. I want to be able to do this : Size.X = 10 ; int i = Size.X ; _declspec lets you do this but it can't use private methods

Comment: @GiwrgosTsopanoglou So, if you make the methods public, you can use `_declspec`, so you can do what you want, yes? So I asked, why don't you make them public? Wouldn't that *enable* you to do what you want, not prevent it?

Comment: @hyde what is the purpose of being able to do the same thing in two ways?

Comment: @GiwrgosTsopanoglou The purpose is to be able to do it the way you want. Being able to do it another way as a side effect is beside the point, at worst requiring extra documentation: "Do not call directly, may be removed in future version" and marking it deprecated if possible, to stop IDE from offering it with Intellisense. It's not optimal, but I don't see a real problem either.

Comment: That's a nice point of view... thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i make a property that uses functions which CAN'T be used
>   outside the class?

Only by using another language, I'm afraid.  Standard C++ has no such property sugar (sadly), and while there are some hacks, none of them are very pretty, including Microsoft's.  See here for some more discussion on your specific issue of private methods being incompatible with the Microsoft `declspec(property)` extension:
http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/11/an-almost-useful-language-extension/

Comment: Ok, this is exactly what i needed. The article you link was perfect for my issue. Thanks :)